# ¿Qué le agregarían o cambiarían a esta función característica?

Tags: python

Para aprender un poco más, que agregarían o cambiarían en la siguiente función característica:

```
def fun_car(x, A, interval=True):
    ''' 
    Characteristic Function
    
        This function returns 1 if x is in the set "A" and 0 if not.

    Parameters
    ----------

    x : str, int, float
        Value that you need to check if is in "A" or not.

    A : array
        Is a set (can be a mixed set (numerical and/or strings, in this case you need to change interval to False) or a set with only four elements [bool, min, max, bool], in this case, you need to left interval in True. The boolean values in A indicate if the interval is open or closed in the extremes.
    interval : boolean (default value: True)
        This boolean value indicates if A is a mixed set or an interval.
    '''

    if interval:
        if (A[0] and A[3]):
            if ((x>=A[1]) and (x<=A[2])):
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
        elif A[3]:
            if ((x>=A[1]) and (x<A[2])):
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
        elif A[0]:
            if ((x>A[1]) and (x<=A[2])):
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
    else:
        if x in A:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

la idea, es que me ayuden a escribir mejor código.
En este caso, lo que intente es programar la clásica función característica, para un elemento x y un conjunto A que puede o no ser un intervalo.

Desde ya, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede reducir bastante con un par de trucos:

- En vez de `a < b and b < c` python admite el atajo `a < b < c`
- Podemos computar el resultado a retornar como un booleano en vez de un entero. Eso es más compacto y en última instancia siempre puedes hacer `int()` sobre el valor a retornar.

Podria quedar entonces así:

```
def func_car(x, A, interval=True):
  if not interval:
    result = x in A
  else:
    result = A[1] < x < A[2]
    result = result or (A[0] and A[1]==x) or (A[3] and A[2]==x)
  return int(result)
```

Observa que primero miro si `x` está entre los extremos del intervalo abierto. Después añado que sea igual a un extremo si éste está cerrado.

### Bonus

Si la variable `x` está restringida a los enteros, se puede sacar partido de que un objeto `range()` admite la operación `in` y hacer una versión aún más corta (aprovechando además que un booleano es convertido automáticamente a entero en un contexto aritmético):

```
def func_car(x, A, interval=True):
  if interval:
      A = range((not A[0]) + A[1], A[2]+A[3])
  return int(x in A)
```

Answer (score 1):

Se puede compactar a

```
def fun_car(x, A, interval=True):
    if interval:
        if (A[0] and A[3]):
            return i if ((x >= A[1]) and (x <= A[2])) else 0
        elif A[3]:
            return 1 if ((x >= A[1]) and (x < A[2])) else 0
        elif A[0]:
            return 1 if ((x > A[1]) and (x <= A[2])) else 0
    else:
        return 1 if x in A else 0
```

usando la expresión que produce un valor

```
a if una_condicion else b
```

que es la forma corta de

```
if una_condicion:
    a
else:
    b
```

Ojo: puede darse el caso que la función termine sin retornar nada.